# jmeter code to remove crlf from an extracted Url

Tags: javascript, jmeter

I need to remove trailing crlf from a string in jmeter. I have used the following function

```
${__javaScript('${varu_2}'.replace(/[\\r\\n]/g\,""))}
```

> It gives me error "org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException:
>   unterminated string literal (#1)".

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The inline evaluation (*${varu_2}*) of your variable containing multiple lines is broking the javascript evaluation.

For example the javascript would be interpreted as :

```
'line1
line2'.replace(/[\\r\\n]/g\,"")
```

The first line is an unterminated string like the error message tells us.

To avoid this behavior I would recommend using the JMeterVariables object, but since the javascript implementation ([Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/)) does not seems to support well inline regexp, you should use 2 replace function instead of your regular expression:

```
${__javaScript(vars.get('varu_2').replace( "\r"\, "" ).replace("\n"\,""))}
```

Or if you prefer, with a [beanshell function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__BeanShell) you can use any regular expression you :

```
${__BeanShell(vars.get("varu_2").replaceAll("[\r\n]"\,""))}
```